# Custom 404 doesn't look like it's supposed to

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404, customization, background-image

I designed my own 404 error which you can find here:
http://www.ianbauters.be/errors/404.html (this one works)

But when I trigger a 404 by going to http://www.ianbauters.be/qsdfhj everything is there except for the orange background image I use.

Anyone has any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Relative path seems to be the problem. Nice design BTW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a relative path to the URL in your CSS is the problem. For example...

```
url('assets/images/opacity.png')
```

Try making it absolute...

```
url('/errors/assets/images/opacity.png')
```

**Edit** - something else to be aware of...

When using `url` in CSS via the `<style>` tag, relative paths will always be relative to the current page location.  When using `url` in CSS via the `<link>` tag and `.css` files, the path will be relative to the *location of the `.css` file*.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have added a relative path for the background image turn it into absolute and you will have no more problems

```
.oh {
   ...
   background-image: url('/assets/images/opacity.png');
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you view the both pages using firebug, you will notice the error on the second page, it's loading image from http://www.ianbauters.be/assets/images/opacity.png
but the correct url is http://www.ianbauters.be/errors/assets/images/opacity.png, just use the whole url

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background-image: url('/errors/assets/images/opacity.png');
```

instead of

```
background-image: url('assets/images/opacity.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the url in css for `.oh`

from

```
url("assets/images/opacity.png")
```

to

```
url("/errors/assets/images/opacity.png");
```